# cannot see apache tomcat homepage

Tags: apache, tomcat

I installed apache tomcat and started the service by double clicking on apache-tomcat-8.0.9\bin\startup.bat file, the survice started successfully in 547ms, later I tried opening the homepage of tomacat by entering
    localhost:8080 in my cleint
 ,all I could see is

```
HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.IllegalStateException: No output folder
```

with a     message java.lang.IllegalStateException: No output folder.

If i don't mention the output folder, am I not supposed to see the homepage of tomcat ?

also I did stop the service by double clicking on
apache-tomcat-8.0.9\bin\startup.ba    file, then I started the service using eclipse then tried opening in my client, then I got a 404 error.

I have no clue where am I going wrong, please give me some suggestions so that i can solve this, also what is the root folder of tomcat in order to put my project folder ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to give appropriate rights to the subfolders of the Tomcat directory. In your case 'temp' and 'work', so the servercan store temporary files and precompiled Jsp.

Comment: I changed the permission by doing this : right click on tomcat folder -> properties ->security -> provide full control for all the available option and now the result is this : HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.index_jsp

Comment: Got it. I just used run as administrator approach. I did this: went to the folder path(c:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-8.0.9\bin) using command prompt then in the next command i just wrote startup to run server using startup.bat file, then in my client I just entered http://localhost:8080 & IT WORKED

Comment: That means the access rights problem still remains. You need to check the directories right again. Not a good idea to run a server a admin ;)